# How to show that a r.v. is normally distributed and that a r.v. is not almost surely constant

Tags: normal-distribution, almost-everywhere

Let $L(Y) = N(0,1)$ and set for some constant a>0:
$$Z=Y1_{|Y|≤a}−Y1_{|Y|>a}$$

Hence, $Y+Z=2Y1_{|Y|≤a}$, that is
$$Y+Z=2Y$$ if |Y|≤a $$Y+Z=0$$ if |Y|>a. How can I show that:$$1)L(Z) = N(0,1)$$ and $$2) Y+Z$$ is not almost surely a constant?

Comment: For 1), I would calculate the characteristic function of $Z$. For 2), I would calculate $P(Y+Z>0)$.

Comment: You can compare the CDFs of $Z$ and $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. For the second part, prove that $P(Y+Z=0)$ is strictly between 0 and 1, which is impossible for constant RVs.

Comment: Thank You @kimchilover

Comment: Thank You @SangchulLee